# Adding existing Jobs to a MultiJob

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

The [Jenkins Job DSL plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) (version 1.42) allows defining MultiJobs:

```
multiJob('MyMultiJob'){
    steps{
        phase('First')
            phaseJob('JobA'){
                #job configuration
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to define a job and add it to a MultiJob in separate steps like in the following example?

```
jobA = job('JobA')

multiJob('MyMultiJob'){
    steps{
        phase('First')
            jobA
        }
    }
}
```

Being forced to define many different jobs inside the MultiJob definition seems complicated and adds a lot of complexity. Are there workarounds? Is it possible to move the definition of a phase job to a function outside the MultiJob definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
def j= {
  parameters {
    propertiesFile('my1.properties')
  }
}

multiJob('example') {
    steps {
        phase('First') {
            phaseJob('JobZ', j)
        }
        phase('Second') {
            phaseJob('JobA', j)
            phaseJob('JobB')
            phaseJob('JobC')
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can use 'j'. The closure syntax outside the parameters is syntactic sugar and the method call assumes the closure is in fact the last parameter

Output from the [job dsl playground](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/)

```
<com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobProject plugin='jenkins-multijob-plugin@1.8'>
    <actions></actions>
    <description></description>
    <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
    <properties></properties>
    <scm class='hudson.scm.NullSCM'></scm>
    <canRoam>true</canRoam>
    <disabled>false</disabled>
    <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
    <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
    <triggers class='vector'></triggers>
    <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
    <builders>
        <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuilder>
            <phaseName>Second</phaseName>
            <continuationCondition>SUCCESSFUL</continuationCondition>
            <phaseJobs>
                <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
                    <jobName>JobZ</jobName>
                    <currParams>true</currParams>
                    <exposedSCM>true</exposedSCM>
                    <disableJob>false</disableJob>
                    <killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>FAILURE</killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>
                    <configs>
                        <hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.FileBuildParameters>
                            <propertiesFile>my1.properties</propertiesFile>
                            <failTriggerOnMissing>false</failTriggerOnMissing>
                        </hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.FileBuildParameters>
                    </configs>
                </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
            </phaseJobs>
        </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuilder>
        <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuilder>
            <phaseName>Third</phaseName>
            <continuationCondition>SUCCESSFUL</continuationCondition>
            <phaseJobs>
                <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
                    <jobName>JobA</jobName>
                    <currParams>true</currParams>
                    <exposedSCM>true</exposedSCM>
                    <disableJob>false</disableJob>
                    <killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>FAILURE</killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>
                    <configs>
                        <hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.FileBuildParameters>
                            <propertiesFile>my1.properties</propertiesFile>
                            <failTriggerOnMissing>false</failTriggerOnMissing>
                        </hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.FileBuildParameters>
                    </configs>
                </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
                <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
                    <jobName>JobB</jobName>
                    <currParams>true</currParams>
                    <exposedSCM>true</exposedSCM>
                    <disableJob>false</disableJob>
                    <killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>FAILURE</killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>
                    <configs class='java.util.Collections$EmptyList'></configs>
                </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
                <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
                    <jobName>JobC</jobName>
                    <currParams>true</currParams>
                    <exposedSCM>true</exposedSCM>
                    <disableJob>false</disableJob>
                    <killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>FAILURE</killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>
                    <configs class='java.util.Collections$EmptyList'></configs>
                </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
            </phaseJobs>
        </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuilder>
    </builders>
    <publishers></publishers>
    <buildWrappers></buildWrappers>
</com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobProject>
```